# Capistrano, Mercurial and branches

Tags: mercurial, capistrano, deployment, branch

It is my understanding that although Mercurial has support from branches, the community generally clone repos instead of creating branches. Similar to the Darcs model, unlike the Git model.

I'm deploying a Ruby on Rails app with Capistrano and there I'd like to separate the production from the development branch. Should I point Capistrano to a different repo or should I use branches?

Has anyone used one model or the other of branching while dealing with Capistrano? Any problems with either?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

yes mercurial supports [several branching models](http://stevelosh.com/blog/2009/08/a-guide-to-branching-in-mercurial//) cloning is probably the most common.

this certainly sounds like the ideal use of a named branch to me, but its ultimately a personal preference thing

Comment: I hesitate to just go and do it that way because I've found branches in Mercurial not that powerful, like in Git, and the community generally pointed to using clones instead of branches for branching code.

Comment: What do you mean by "not that powerful"?  I've used named branches a number of times for exactly this type of problem and it's worked great.  What do you feel is missing from the branching?

Answer (score 4):

In your config/deploy.rb put

```
set :branch, "your_branch"
```